# Erlang: find word from list and return True

Tags: erlang, erl

How can I make function to search for a word in list and return true if word in list.

Example :

```
find(string) ->
    List = ["bye", "hello", "hi"],
    case string in List of
        true ->
            true;
        _ ->
            false
    end.

find("hi there, how are you today?").
```

And the text is : "hi there, How are you today?"

it should return true cuz hi in list.

Comment: I generally put as much work in an answer as the person puts in the question. What have you tried?

Comment: @NeilLocketz I edited my question. I'm newer in Erlang so I don't know how it'll be the function. thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1> F = fun(String) -> List = ["bye", "hello", "hi"], lists:any(fun(S) -> lists:member(S, List) end, string:tokens(String, " ,.?!")) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.54118792>
2> F("hi, what did you tried so far?").
true
```